# Can you reset a static variable?

Tags: java, methods, static

I have been trying to reset a static variable that will keep count when certain methods are run. I want to be able to reset the counter after I return the output of one of the methods. The getEfficency will pull the value just fine, but after I run the getEfficency I would like for the static variable to be reset to 0, so that my program can run the other compute method.

```
public class Sequence {

    private static  int efficencyCount;

    public static int computeIterative(int n) {
        efficencyCount++;
    }

    public static int computeRecursive() {
        efficencyCount++;

    }

    public static int getEfficiency() {

        return efficencyCount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a temp variable and set hour static to 0. 
Also you should keep protected your static variables to avoid misuse of your variables lutside of your class.

```
public static int getEfficiency (){
   int temp=efficiencyCount;
   efficiencyCount=0;
   return temp; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for editing @Bahramdun-Adil - posted the response from the mobile app before getting to sleep! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a local variable and store the value of count temporarily. Reset the value of efficencyCount and return the value of local temporary count variable.

```
public static int getEfficiency() {
    int count = efficencyCount;
    efficencyCount = 0;
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it as below:

Create a `method`, and reset the `efficencyCount` variable inside this method

```
public static void resetCounter() {
    efficencyCount = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a temporary variable that holds the efficencyCount, then reset efficencyCount to zero.

```
public static int getEfficiency(){
   int temp = efficencyCount;
   efficencyCount = 0;
   return temp;
}
```