# Reset or Clear Static Variable

Tags: variables, static

I am exploring the answer given in the other thread:
[Can you reset a static variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446345/can-you-reset-a-static-variable)
But my query is little different:

```
static int counter = 1;
public void captureField(String fieldValue, String type) throws Throwable {
    String value = "Hello";
    writeFieldValue(value, type, counter++);
}

public static void writeFieldValue(String fieldValue, String type, int counter) throws IOException {
    *//File Handling code here*
    sheet.getRow(counter).getCell(5).setCellValue(fieldValue);
}
```

The above code is working fine for the first scenario where counter is incremented properly to add fieldValue in cells sequentially. But, to execute next scenario, counter value should be reset to 1.

The problem is:

'counter' value is not reset to 1 after executing for specific scenario and throws java.lang.NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution. Added another static variable "txnTypex" which will keep checking the type value and whenever the value changes the counter will be reset to 1.

```
static int counter = 1;
static String txnTypex = "";
public void captureField(String fieldValue, String type) throws Throwable {
     String value = "Hello";
     if(!txnTypex.equals(txnType))
        counter=1;

     writeFieldValue(value, type, counter++);
     txnTypex=txnType;
}
```